# Installation of ttk Themes for Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, themes

i'm currently trying to make some of my applications i built using tkinter look better. I read that you can change the theme of tkinter using ttk and got it to work with the built-in themes.

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
import ttkthemes

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

ttk.Style().theme_use('alt')

Button1 =ttk.Button(text="Test").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But as the built-in ones are kind of outdated, i began trying to install external ones from this list: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes . I tried `pip install ttkthemes` and hoped to get the "Adapta" theme to work ( https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes.html ).
I tried to import ttkthemes, but couldn't get it to work. Python cannot find the theme `_tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme::adapta` when executed. So how do i get those external themes imported into python?

Comment: What does "couldn't get it to work" mean? What happened when you tried?

Comment: Oh sorry, i'll add that to the question.

Comment: If I install `ttkthemes` with pip and run the [example given in the doc](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html), replacing "arc" by "adapta", everything works fine.

Comment: You should execute `ttkthemes.themed_style.ThemedStyle(theme="adapta")` instead of `ttk.Style().theme_use('adapta')`.

Comment: @j_4321 I tried using the example given in doc but got the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'ThemedTk'`. I also tried `from ttkthemes.themed_tk import ThemedTk` but got another error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttkthemes.themed_tk'; 'ttkthemes' is not a package`. I can verify that `~.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ttkthemes` does exist and that `ThemeTk` is located in the file `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ttkthemes/themed_tk.py`. How do you do the import?

Comment: @SunBear I do the import exactly like in the example. Are you sure that `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` is in your python path (check `sys.path`)?

Comment: @j_4321 Yes. pip3 install says `Requirement already satisfied: ttkthemes in ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.2.2)`. Also that path is return by `sys.path`. The funny thing is that when I typed out line by line the example in Idle, it works. However, when I ran the example script,  it fails because `ImportError: cannot import name 'ThemedTk'`. I am bewildered.

Comment: @j_4321 I finally figured out my issue. I had another file in the same directory named `ttkthemes.py` and that caused a circular import situation... I had also accidentally named the example script as `ttkthemes.py` and that caused the same problem too. LOL... Everything works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

In your python terminal, type 'pip install ttkthemes'. Now the exemple document should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The ttkthemes module has its own style class called ThemedStyle. That can be used to select all the extra themes provided by the ttkthemes module as well as the themes that come with tkinter.ttk.

```py
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
import ttkthemes

root = tk.Tk()

# style = ttk.Style()               # Instead of this...
style = ttkthemes.ThemedStyle()     # do this

style.theme_use('itft1')            # extra themes work now

ttk.Button(width=30, text="Test").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]